# Typescript typings in dynamic programming?

Tags: typescript, dynamic-programming, typescript-typings

I was trying to get types in typescript for dynamic programming.
I am getting an error at line

```
        const { oldListIndex, getNewFunc } = getFunc(newObjItem, oldObj);
```

The error is

Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((item: {}, list: T) => { oldListIndex: number; getNewFunc: {}; }) | { [K in { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K : never; }[keyof T]]: funcIterator; }' has no compatible call signatures.

And Line

```
    oldObj = newObj
```

The error is

Type 'Partial' is not assignable to type 'T'.

```
type funcIterator<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ?
    (item: U, list: T) => funcIterator<U> extends never ?
        { oldListIndex: number, } : { oldListIndex: number, getNewFunc: funcIterator<U> }
    : T extends object ? { [K in objectKeys<T>]: funcIterator<T[K]> } : never;

type objectKeys<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K : never
}[keyof T];

function updateOldObj<T>(oldObj: T, newObj: Partial<T>, getFunc: funcIterator<T>) {
    if (Array.isArray(newObj) && Array.isArray(oldObj)) {
        newObj.forEach(newObjItem => {

            const { oldListIndex, getNewFunc } = getFunc(newObjItem, oldObj);
            oldObj[oldListIndex] = updateOldObj(oldObj[oldListIndex], newObjItem, getNewFunc)
        });
        return oldObj;
    } else if (typeof newObj === 'object' && typeof oldObj === 'object') {
        Object.keys(newObj).forEach((newObjKey) => {

            oldObj[newObjKey] = updateOldObj(oldObj[newObjKey],
                newObj[newObjKey], (getFunc) ? getFunc[newObjKey] : undefined);
        });
        return oldObj;
    } else {
        oldObj = newObj
        return oldObj;
    }
}
```

Any Help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will not be able to call an conditional type that has unresolved type parameters (like `T`) you will need to use a type assertion

Comment: Hmmm... ok i could give it a try. Thanks